# hoses instead of pipes

Tags: plumbing, water, installation

Quick question that came to my mind earlier today:

When installing a water system (concealed installation), why does one use pipes. It seems to me that hoses would be easier to install, more flexible and might reduce effects like rushing sounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the picture below you will see **pex tubing**.  This has become the industry norm in some areas of the US - I know some countries have adopted similar things and some haven't.  The compression fittings are supposedly made to last longer than than a soldered copper joints - jury is still out on that.  Let's see what complaints there are in 10-20 years.

My problem with these is the drinking water.  Copper does a great job of not letting bacteria grow in it and it has been used for years with no issues.  All of the plumbing going to sinks in my house is copper.  I use pex for toilets, showers, and things like that.

[image]

Some good links on coppers anti-bacterial qualities:

- [HowStuffWorks](http://health.howstuffworks.com/medicine/healthcare/copper-kills-microbes-and-bacteria-could-save-lives.htm)
- [ScienceDaily](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/02/110216120436.htm)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_properties_of_copper)

On the other side of the argument is the idea that PEX has issues in biofilm formation and passing on toxins/bacteria - [California study here](http://calpipes.org/ProtectingCalifornians_PEX.asp).  This side, I don't really buy that much because you can read counters for most things.  I just know that copper has a lot of good qualities and installing it isn't that big of a deal so will leave that for the main and drinking water.

Comment: That bacteria argument is most probably the one I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Brad we generally avoid really minor edits but I made it in this case since it has a big impact on the intended meaning.  Good eye!

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about the bacteria issue, unless you're distributing filtered water.  In most areas, the water contains so much free chlorine (or other equivalent disinfectant) that the chances of anything growing are minimal.

Comment: @Jules - I understand that and maybe I am going overboard but would like to error on the side of safety when my whole family is drinking from the tap.

Comment: @Jules poison (chlorine) is not always added to water supplies. Where I am in New Zealand we don't have these additives in our water and plastic tubing may well grow bacteria... good to know DMoore - thanks

Comment: DMoore do you know of any actual evidence supporting the claim that PEX allows bacterial growth more than copper?  AFAIK copper doesn't have any magical anti-bacterial properties.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_properties_of_copper) says it's still under investigation, but some recent studies have shown copper's effectiveness at killing E. coli.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - added a few links.  There are studies that show that and probably counter studies.  To me it is just too new for drinking water and copper has too many good traits to stop using it.  Like I said, I have PEX in my house.  But even on my flips I run copper to kitchen/bathroom sinks, PEX everywhere else.  I have had subs ask why, and I just say because - really I don't want to think about ever causing an issue.

Comment: While copper has been shown to be antibacterial, as soon as the thin film of oxidization forms on the inside of the copper tubing the benefits are moot because water doesn't come into contact with any copper ions.

Comment: @Ethereal - I don't know about that.  I have a copper pipe in my garage that I pulled from my shower that was 50 years old.  Looks almost brand new, inside and out.  I think there is sediment buildup at the bottom sometimes but I have not seen huge oxidization unless water was turned off in a home for a long period.

Comment: @DMoore, the oxidization layer is very thin, and would look like dull, darker copper vs new shiny copper.  Try scratching the inside surface to see if you notice a difference in appearance.  You can also try dropping a bit of reactive chemical on the inside surface to see if the copper reacts, and if not that would indicate a protective oxidization layer.

Comment: @scrowler are you sure your water isn't chlorinated?  http://www.drinkingwater.esr.cri.nz/general/nzprocesses.asp suggests that (at least) most of the drinking water supplies in NZ do have chlorine added ("The most common [method of water] treatment is chlorination").